# How to add Custom Registeration field from admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Hi i have a form in admin and i want that when select the type this values should reflect on an appropriate selected form but am not able to do so can anyone guide me here is a screenshot

[image]

**InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category   Eecom
 * @package    Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute
 */
namespace Eecom\CustomCustomerAttribute\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        /**
         * Creating table eecom_customcustomerattribute
         */
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('eecom_customcustomerattribute')
        )->addColumn(
            'customcustomerattribute_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Entity Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'attribute_code',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Attribute  Code'
        )->addColumn(
            'attribute_label',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
            'Attribute Label'

            )->addColumn(
            'sortorder',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
            'Sort Order'

// edited from here
            )->addColumn(
            'inputtypeforstoreowner',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            1,
            ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
            'Input Type For Store Owners'

            )->addColumn(
            'valuerequired',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            1,
            ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
            'Value Required'


            )->addColumn(
            'inputvalidationforstoreowner',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            1,
            ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
            'Input Validation For Store Owners'


            )->addColumn(
            'displayfieldinform',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            1,
            ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
            'Dispaly Field In Form'


        )->addColumn(
            'status',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            1,
            ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
            'Status'
        )->setComment(
            'Eecom CustomCustomerAttribute Table'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

i just need suggestion on how to take it further can any one explain it to me it will be a great help.
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * @category   Eecom
 * @package    Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute
 */
 -->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>

        <!-- add new button -->
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Attribute</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">EecomCustomCustomerAttributeGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">customcustomerattribute_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">customcustomerattribute_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">customcustomerattribute_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="string">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Delete selected items?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="eecom_customcustomerattribute/items/massDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="status">
                <settings>
                    <type>status</type>
                    <label translate="true">Change status</label>
                    <actions>
                        <action name="0">
                            <type>enable</type>
                            <label translate="true">Enable</label>
                            <url path="eecom_customcustomerattribute/items/massStatus">
                                <param name="status">1</param>
                            </url>
                        </action>
                        <action name="1">
                            <type>disable</type>
                            <label translate="true">Disable</label>
                            <url path="eecom_customcustomerattribute/items/massStatus">
                                <param name="status">0</param>
                            </url>
                        </action>
                    </actions>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">customcustomerattribute_id</item>
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="eecom_customcustomerattribute/items/inlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.eecom_customcustomerattribute_index_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">customcustomerattribute_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <!-- id -->
        <column name="customcustomerattribute_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">customcustomerattribute_id</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

      <!--   for attribute code -->
        <column name="attribute_code">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Attribute Code</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

       <!--  for attribute lable -->
        <column name="attribute_label">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Attribute Label</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

    <!-- <column name="inputtypeforstoreowner">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Eecom\CustomCustomerAttribute\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Input Type For Store Owners</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    </column> -->


        <!-- status enable disbale -->
        <column name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Eecom\CustomCustomerAttribute\Model\Source\Status</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Eecom\CustomCustomerAttribute\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomCustomerAttributeActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">customcustomerattribute_id</item>
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: try this for add dependency fields https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304556/dependent-custom-option-in-magento-2/304617#304617

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/308012/magento2-menu-not-visible-on-custom-module can you please ans this

Comment: let me update it's helps you ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <field name="priority">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\CustomOption</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_ModuleName/js/form/element/options</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Priority</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">priority</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>

<field name="order_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Order</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\view\adminhtml\web\js\components**

**options.js**

```
        define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($,_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({
              /**
         * Init
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.fieldDepend(this.value());
            return this;
        },
        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            this.fieldDepend(value);
            return this._super();
        },
        /**
         * Update field dependency
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        fieldDepend: function (value) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var field_value = uiRegistry.get('index = order_id'); // add your field name
                if (value == 1) {
                    field_value.show();
                } else {
                    field_value.hide();
                }
            }, 1);
            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

This line added js to your form field

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_ModuleName/js/form/element/options</item>
```

> **Update**
>
> I create form and in which one priority field and order field.
>
> once priority is high (value - 1) show order field and priority is low (value - 0) hide order field.

```
var field_value = uiRegistry.get('index = order_id');
```

> this line get my order field by using it's field name

```
<field name="order_id">
```

[Reference Link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html)

For adding field dependency [click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304556/dependent-custom-option-in-magento-2/304617#304617)

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: can you explain what this code does??coz am not able to figure it out

Comment: Are you create form using UI components ??

Comment: yes am using ui component

Comment: So now show your ui components code. In your require Field add JS components

Comment: wait i will share my ui component code

Comment: check the updated question

Comment: you have to added custom js to your form field. answer is updated.

Comment: var field_value = uiRegistry.get('index = order_id');  can you explain this

Comment: check my update answer