# Magento2 - Menu Not Visible On Custom Module

Tags: magento2, magento2menu

Hi I have installed a new module but It's is not visible in Menu.

Here is a `menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Technogex_CustomerAttribute::core" title="Technogex" translate="title" module="Technogex_CustomerAttribute" parent="Magento_Backend::stores"   sortOrder="100"  resource="Technogex_CustomerAttribute::core"/>
        <add id="Technogex_CustomerAttribute::customer_attributes" title="Customer Attribute" module="Technogex_CustomerAttribute" sortOrder="70" parent="Technogex_CustomerAttribute::core" action="customerattribute/attribute" resource="Technogex_CustomerAttribute::customer_attributes"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Please take a look someone.

Comment: please check your module is enable or not using php bin/magento module:s

Comment: its enabled i had checked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Technogex_CustomerAttribute::core" title="Technogex" translate="title" module="Technogex_CustomerAttribute" parent="Magento_Backend::stores"   sortOrder="100"  resource="Technogex_CustomerAttribute::core"/>
        <add id="Technogex_CustomerAttribute::customer_attributes" title="Customer Attribute" module="Technogex_CustomerAttribute" sortOrder="70" parent="Technogex_CustomerAttribute::core" action="customerattribute/attribute" resource="Technogex_CustomerAttribute::customer_attributes"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

your code is Right.

please run Magento command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

clear your browser cache and your menu are show here

[image]

Comment: i have already tried this but it does not show up

Comment: i have add your code in my module and check then it's run perfectly. can you give me file path where you add this menu.xml ?

Comment: you can see above screen shot your menu add into Store menu. you doing somthing wrong please try again.

Comment: please check and update me