# Show categories based on first dropdown values in admin form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have added two components using Ui component in the admin form,
the first one is a simple dropdown and the second one is a category selector

I want to show the parent category and its subcategories based on the values selected from the first dropdown.

how can I do that?

Comment: You need to use phtml file, & add fields in it , then simply use ajax to send request based on the selected category , return its subcategories. That would be quite easier.

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304617/82670