# How to show sku in text box when type productId in the field using js magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to fill sku filed when type of productId

[image]

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304617/82670

Comment: @Msquare here i am not using the select field. using an input field.

Comment: You can use search select which is best way.

Comment: Thank you, but requirement is input.