# Magento 2.4.6: How to display Order IDs Based on Selected Customers in a UI Form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ui-form, magento2.4.6

I've created a UI component form that consists of two dropdown fields. The first dropdown successfully displays customer IDs and names. However, I'm encountering challenges with the second dropdown, which is intended to show order IDs related to the selected customer. Despite my attempts to use JavaScript components, I'm not able to get the desired outcome. Could you provide guidance on how to implement this feature effectively?

Below are the ui component fields:

```
<field name="dropdown1">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Dropdown 1</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/form/element/options</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">module</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">dropdown1</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="dropdown2">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Dropdown 2</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">module</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">dropdown2</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Below is my javascript file:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'jquery'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, $) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            console.log(value);
            var field2 = uiRegistry.get('index = dropdown2');
            if (field2) {
                var selectElement = field2.selectNode;
                $(selectElement).empty(); // Clear previous options

                // Make an AJAX request to fetch orders for the specific customer
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/admin/module/index/orders',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { customer_id: value, form_key: window.FORM_KEY },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        if (response.orders) {
                            response.orders.forEach(function (order) {
                                var option = document.createElement('option');
                                option.value = order.entity_id;
                                option.text = order.increment_id;
                                selectElement.appendChild(option);
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error('AJAX request error:', error);
                    }
                });
            }
            
            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/369641/82670 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Way

> Routes File - **Custom/Module/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="customroute" frontName="customroute">
            <module name="Custom_module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Ui component Form
> -**Custom/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/custom_data_form.xml**

Add the below fields into your UI component form and update the code as per your proper path

```
<field name="dropdown1">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Custom\Module\Model\Config\Source\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customroute/data/orderids">
                <param name="_nosid">1</param>
            </item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Custom_Module/js/form/element/options</item>
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Dropdown 1</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">module</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">dropdown1</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="dropdown2">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Dropdown 2</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">module</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">dropdown2</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

The below code is calling your Ajax controller of path. please update as per your path

```
<item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customroute/data/orderids">
       <param name="_nosid">1</param>
</item>
```

> JS File - **Custom/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/options.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/url'
], function($, _, uiRegistry, select, modal, url) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        onUpdate: function(value) {
            var self = this;
            var linkUrl = url.build('customajax');
            var customerId = $('select[name="dropdown1"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: self.url + linkUrl,
                showLoader: true,
                data: { form_key: window.FORM_KEY, 'value': value , 'customer_id': customerId},
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result.message);
                    if (result.status == 200) {
                        $.each(result.ordersdata,function(key, value)
                        {
                            $('select[name="dropdown2"]').append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

> Controller Path - **Custom/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Data/OrderIds.php**

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Data;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class OrderIds extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        if (isset($params['customer_id'])) {
                // Based on customer id get orders data and pass to return response
                // Add Logic Here
                $response = [
                    'success' => true,
                    'status' => 200,
                    'ordersdata' => array("10001","10002","10003","10004"),
                    'message' => 'order data is availabe.'
                ];

            return $resultJson->setData($response);
        }
    }
}
```

Try the above code. First, try to understand then start the implementation
If there is any issue let me know

Answer (score 0):

> **Add the below Two fields into your UI form**

```
    <field name="customer_id"  formElement="select" component="Vendorname_ModuleName/js/components/select-customer" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="mapper" xsi:type="object">Vendorname\ModuleName\Model\Mapper</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <required>true</required>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
            <label translate="true">Select Customer</label>
            <dataScope>data.customer</dataScope>
            <componentType>field</componentType>
            <listens>
                <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
            </listens>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Vendorname\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Create\Form\Customer\CustomerOptions"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
    <field name="order_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select Order</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="mapper" xsi:type="object">Vendorname\ModuleName\Model\Mapper</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataScope>data.order_id</dataScope>
            <listens>
                <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
            </listens>
        </settings>
    </field>
```

**app/code/Vendorname/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/js/components**

**select-customer.js**

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select',
    'uiRegistry',
], function (Select,uiRegistry) {
    'use strict';
    return Select.extend({
         defaults: {
            mapper: []
        },

         initialize: function (){
            var order_id = uiRegistry.get('index = order_id');
            order_id.hide();
            return this._super();
            return this.setDependentOptions(this.value());
        },

        setParsed: function (data) {
            var option = this.parseData(data);
            if (data.error) {
                return this;
            }
            this.options([]);
            this.setOption(option);
            this.set('newOption', option);
        },

        onUpdate: function (value) {
           var order_id_1 = uiRegistry.get('index = order_id');
           order_id_1.show();
           this.setDependentOptions(value);
           return this._super();
        },

        setDependentOptions: function (value) {
           var options = this.mapper['map'][value];
           var field = uiRegistry.get('index = order_id');
           field.setOptions(options);
           return this;
        },

        parseData: function (data) {
            return {
                value: data.customer.entity_id,
                label: data.customer.name
            };
        }
    });
});
```

**app/code/Vendorname/ModuleName/Model**

**Mapper.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\ModuleName\Model;

class Mapper
{
    public $map;
    public $map1;
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->map = $this->makeMap();
        $this->map1 = $this->makeMapItem();
    }
    private function makeMap()
    {
        if ($this->map == null) {
            $this->map = $this->buildMap();
        }
        return $this->map;
    }
    private function makeMapItem()
    {
        if ($this->map1 == null) {
            $this->map1 = $this->buildMapItems();
        }
        return $this->map1;
    }
    private function buildMap()
    {
        $order = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $items = [];
        $options = [];
        $result = [];
        foreach ($order->getData() as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute['customer_id'] != '') {
                $result[$attribute['customer_id']][] = [
                    'label' => $attribute['increment_id'], 'value' => $attribute['increment_id'],
                ];
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    private function buildMapItems()
    {
        $result = [];
        $orderCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        foreach ($orderCollection as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getCustomerId() != '') {
                $order_id = $attribute->getEntityId();
                $increment_id = $attribute->getIncrementId();
                $order_data = $this->orderRepository->get($order_id);
                if (!empty($order_data)) {
                    foreach ($order_data->getAllItems() as $value) {
                        $result[$increment_id][] = [
                            'label' => $value->getName(), 'value' => $value->getProductId(),
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendorname/ModuleName/Ui/Component/Create/Form/Customer**

**CustomerOptions.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Create\Form\Customer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory as CustomerCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class CustomerOptions implements OptionSourceInterface
{

    protected $customerCollectionFactory;
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $request;
    protected $customerTree;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerCollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->customerCollectionFactory = $customerCollectionFactory;
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getCustomerTree();
    }
    protected function getCustomerTree()
    {
        $customerById = [];
        if ($this->customerTree === null) {
            $collection = $this->customerCollectionFactory->create();
            if (count($collection)) {
                $collection->addNameToSelect();
                foreach ($collection as $customer) {
                    $customerId = $customer->getEntityId();
                    $Ordercollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
                    $Ordercollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);
                    if (count($Ordercollection)) {
                        if (!isset($customerById[$customerId])) {
                            $customerById[$customerId] = [
                                'value' => $customerId,
                            ];
                            $customerById[$customerId]['label'] = $customer->getName() .
                            " ( " . $customer->getEmail() . ")";
                        }
                    }
                }
                $cust_count = count($customerById);
                if ($cust_count == 0) {
                    $options[] = [
                        'label' => 'You have no Order',
                        'value' => '',
                    ];
                    return $options;
                }
                $this->customerTree = $customerById;
                return $this->customerTree;
            } else {
                $options[] = [
                    'label' => 'You have no Oreder',
                    'value' => '',
                ];
                return $options;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image]

Reference Code : [Dependent Custom option in Magento-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304556/dependent-custom-option-in-magento-2/304617#304617)