# How to Display and change values of 2nd multi-select dropdown by selecting 1st drop-down?

Tags: magento2, multiselect, ui-select

I want to show multi-select drop-down with check-boxes(like categories on product edit page in admin panel) which values are depends on 1st drop-down(which is single select) in my custom Ui component form in admin panel.

Comment: yes it is possible i will add an answer in a while

Comment: I have done that task by using phtml and jQuery but I want by UI component, if it is possible please let me know.
Thanks for the response.